# Changing tooltips in a custom view

Tags: cocoa, tooltip, nsview

I've got a sample project at:

http://ericgorr.net/cocoadev/tooltip.zip

What I would like to do is define a single tooltip rect for an entire view but be able to change the tooltip as the cursor moves inside of the view.

Is there a way to do that? Is there a way to force it to hide the current tooltip and display a new one while calling view:stringForToolTip:point:userData:?

I could create my own window that simulates a real tooltip, but wanted to make sure there was nothing built-in that would support this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the MAAttachedWindow sample project: 
http://mattgemmell.com/source/ 
Great start for creating custom tooltips.

NSView has specific handlers for mouse events. 
Simply change the NSView (tooltip) based on these events. 
I added some snippets to get you started.

```
- (void)mouseMove:(NSEvent *)theEvent {

    NSPoint mousePositionInWindow = [theEvent locationInWindow];

}

- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {

}

- (void)mouseDragged:(NSEvent *)theEvent {

}

- (void)mouseUp:(NSEvent *)theEvent {

}
```

*Response to comment:*

Once I struggled with exactly the same problem: One view with continuous tooltip updates showing the cursor position and some additional information. I got it never working with the native tooltips. Finally i came up with the solution above, which is easy to implement and made it even look better.

Instead of using the separate window, you can also draw the custom tooltip inside the NSView itself, in relation to the cursor position. You can also put an extra NSView on top of the existing NSView to show the custom tooltips.

I don't like the native tooltip behavior. Apparently they have build-in time-delays which cannot be changed, for example: The cursor has to be on one position for some time to show the tooltip for the first time. Once the first tooltip showed up, the next will show with much less delay, but it's still quite annoying.

Of cours, you can always show the info in a label located near the view, which is really easy to implement. But that is no real answer to your question :)

Comment: So, basically, what you are saying is that I need to roll my own custom tooltip window and that the built-in support for tooltips in Cocoa cannot do what I need them to do?

Comment: Added some additional comments to the answer :)

Comment: "mouseMove" ? I remembered that it should be "mouseMoved".